# grouped subtotals with KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I'm new to knockoutjs, and I've ran across a problem I can't seem to get to the bottom of.  I have a sample of my problem at http://jsfiddle.net/stoberman/72zAq/3/.  Basically, I have multiple groups of questions, each which should subtotal to a different field. (Ultimately, the subtotals will also total, but that is a problem for another day.)  What's happening instead is both subtotal fields are showing the total for the last group (in the example, the 3rd group). Any help pointing out what I'm missing would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the `var` in `var self = this;` in the QuestionGroup constructor, thus reassigning the existing variable. Here's an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/DFyVz/4/

Comment: Thanks.  That did the trick. Knew it would be something dumb.